# How to use Saxon to perform schema validation

Tags: xml, schema, saxon

I need to run schema validation via a command line. I came across
[this](https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation11/schema-processing/commandline.html)

I created this attempt

java -Xmx2000m -jar C:\Saxon\saxon9ee.jar -xsd:"C:\Documents\Test\claw.xsd" -s:C:\Documents\Test\finalOutput\F4.xml

but got an error no style sheet found.

Please assist.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use e.g.

```
java -cp C:\Saxon\saxon9ee.jar com.saxonica.Validate -xsd:"C:\Documents\Test\claw.xsd" -s:C:\Documents\Test\finalOutput\F4.xml
```

Comment: Also, of course, you'll need to make sure that your Saxon-EE license file is picked up.

Comment: @Martin Honnen  this doesn't seem to work I get the error:Warning at xs:import on line 70 column 110 of ns_directory.xsd:
  The schema document at ns_org.xsd is not being read because schema components for this
  namespace are already available. To force the schema document to be read, set
  --multipleSchemaImports:on
No more warnings will be displayed
Stylesheet file com.saxonica.Validate does not exist

Comment: @David, I would suggest you try a simple XML and schema sample, then, if you have managed that and run into warnings related to a particular schema set, open a new question with all the details. I can't tell from your comment what you have tried and why you get that output, it seems rather odd that you first get a warning on schema imports to later get a warning about a "stylesheet" file. Is that the result of a single command with `java -cp C:\Saxon\saxon9ee.jar com.saxonica.Validate` or are you still trying with `java -jar`? So using `java -cp` and not `java -jar` is essential.